# How do I write a regex that matches a certain character within brackets?

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

So I have a string that's like this,

```
(name|address)
([name|address])
[name|address]
```

So I want to check for '|' character and ignore if it's in the brackets like I have shown in the example.

I have added this regex but it's not capturing all scenarios that I have described.

```
\\|(?![^(]*\\))
```

**Edit:**

If I have string like this,

`|Hello all, | morning [name|address] |`

Then I am breaking the string by `|` character. But I don't want to consider `|` character which are inside the brackets while breaking the string.

Comment: Do you mean `|` in  `([name|address])` must be matched?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I meant if I have a string like this, `hello all | morning [name|address] all|` then I am breaking the string by `|` character. But I don't want to consider `|` character which is inside the brackets.

Comment: So, `"\\|(?![^\\]\\[]*])"`? See https://regex101.com/r/1dB8kM/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is still considering the pipeline character in string like this, `(hello|all)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s = "|Hello all, | morning [name|address] |";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\\([^()]*\\)|\\[[^\\]\\[]*]|[^|])+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        while (matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group().trim()); 
        } 
    }
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2KJ5zA/1) and the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/ULO4VZ).

*Details*:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `\([^()]*\)|` - `(`, zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`, and then a `)` char, or
  - `\[[^\]\[]*]|` - `[`, zero or more chars other than a `[` or `]` char, and then a `]` char, or
  - `[^|]` - any single char other than a pipe char
- `)+` - end of the group, repeat one or more times.

Note that in Android, Java, ICU regex flavors, both `[` and `]` must be escaped inside character classes.

Comment: what if there is paranthesis instead of square brackets? This still considers `|` character when in paranthesis instead of square brackets.

Comment: @xorax12 Then add them, `String pat = "\\|(?![^\\]\\[()]*[\\])])";`, or match your items with `"(?:\\([^()]*\\)|\\[[^\\]\\[]*]|[^|\\]\\[()])+"`